# Why do I have to keep unlocking my SSH key?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent

I ran some X applications using `ssh -Y my_address` and now it asks me to unlock my RSA key every time I use it.  I used to only have to unlock it once a day.  What's going on?

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: Is ssh-agent running in the background?

Comment: @Grumbel: Yep, it is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found it elsewhere.  I had to do this:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Ugh... it happens again when I restart my computer.  Running this command fixes it, but it doesn't seem like I should have to do this every day.

Comment: create a startup script that runs this command at boot. or adjust your crontab to run it daily.

Comment: +1 thank you - this helped me when I got: "An application wants to access the private key but its locked"  - on running the above, it asked for the passphrase - which was the password I used when creating the key - and on supplying that, that worked - I was now able to pull from bitbucket.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who get's a `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent` when executing `ssh-add` will need to [start `ssh-agent` first](http://funkaoshi.com/blog/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent).

```bsh
    eval `ssh-agent`
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you have fixed this by now, but you might be interested to see a response to a question I recently asked on AskUbuntu.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/36255/why-wont-ssh-agent-save-my-unencrypted-key-for-later-use/36302#36302